# I trained a keras model on google colab. Now not able to load it locally on my system.

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

```
with open('2model.json','r') as f:
json = f.read()
model = model_from_json(json)
model.load_weights("color_tensorflow_real_mode.h5")
```

I trained a keras model on google colab. Now not able to load it locally on my system. Getting this error: ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

How to solve this??
Every time I make a model on colab and try loading it locally I am unable to do so.
Getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c3ed162a8277> in <module>()
----> 1 model = model_from_json(json)
      2 model.load_weights("color_tensorflow_real_mode.h5")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py in model_from_json(json_string, custom_objects)
    349   config = json.loads(json_string)
    350   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 351   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    352 
    353 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     62       module_objects=globs,
     63       custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 64       printable_module_name='layer')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    171             custom_objects=dict(
    172                 list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 173                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    174       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    175         return cls.from_config(config['config'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1290     # First, we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed
   1291     for layer_data in config['layers']:
-> 1292       process_layer(layer_data)
   1293     # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
   1294     # Nodes that cannot yet be processed (if the inbound node

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in process_layer(layer_data)
   1276       from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize as deserialize_layer  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   1277 
-> 1278       layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
   1279       created_layers[layer_name] = layer
   1280 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     62       module_objects=globs,
     63       custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 64       printable_module_name='layer')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    173                 list(custom_objects.items())))
    174       with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
--> 175         return cls.from_config(config['config'])
    176     else:
    177       # Then `cls` may be a function returning a class.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in from_config(cls, config)
   1615         A layer instance.
   1616     """
-> 1617     return cls(**config)
   1618 
   1619 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py in __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
    464         activation=activations.get(activation),
    465         use_bias=use_bias,
--> 466         kernel_initializer=initializers.get(kernel_initializer),
    467         bias_initializer=initializers.get(bias_initializer),
    468         kernel_regularizer=regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers.py in get(identifier)
    153     return None
    154   if isinstance(identifier, dict):
--> 155     return deserialize(identifier)
    156   elif isinstance(identifier, six.string_types):
    157     config = {'class_name': str(identifier), 'config': {}}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\initializers.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    145       module_objects=globals(),
    146       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 147       printable_module_name='initializer')
    148 
    149 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    161       cls = module_objects.get(class_name)
    162       if cls is None:
--> 163         raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    164     if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):
    165       arg_spec = tf_inspect.getfullargspec(cls.from_config)

ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform
```

Stackoverflow is asking me to add details while I have none to add. Or I am not sure what to add. Please help.

Comment: Do you have the same TensorFlow versions in Colab and in your local machine?

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you have the newest version of `Keras` and `tensorflow` (which are `2.4.4` and `1.11.0`) by running either `pip install keras tensorflow` or `conda install keras tensorflow`.
2. In case it is Google Colab that uses deprecated objects, you may need to  use custom objects:

```py
from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}):
    model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Not sure  if this is your case though.

Answer (score 3):

load the model using

```
 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

instead of

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

I tried using many methods but this is the one that finally worked!

Comment: thank you so much for that post! I used: from keras.models import load_model
It worked for models generated with Google AI platform "runtimeVersion": "2.2", and "pythonVersion": "3.7"

Comment: I want to be provide more details on how it worked: the model was generated on runtime 2.2 - tensorflow 2.2. to load it, I use the following: pip install tensorflow==1.11.0 pip install keras==2.4.0 from keras.models import load_model new_model = load_model(local_model)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error (Unknown layer:name) when I was trying to locally load model trained on Colab. I was trying to change keras version, tensorflow version, conda version etc. and nothing helped. I solved this by saving my model's weights on Colab, locally creating the same model and loading the weights to this model.