# Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform when loading Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

I trained my CNN (VGG) through google colab and generated .h5 file. Now problem is, I can predict my output successfully through google colab but when i download that .h5 trained model file and try to predict output on my laptop, I am getting error when loading the model.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import h5py

# Initialization

loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('./train_personCount_model.h5')
```

And the error:

```
ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform
```

Comment: Probably caused by a Keras version mismatch between google colab's and your local machine's.

Comment: okie let me check..!

Comment: Or it can also be caused by mixing tf.keras and keras (not the same).

Comment: @today maybe you are right..i'll acknowledge if that works or vice-versa.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i have used tf.keras on both platform (i.e. google colab as well as my laptop)

Comment: Welcome to SO; code here is supposed to be *minimal*, i.e. just the necessary to illustrate/reproduce your issue. Arguably, most of your posted code is completely irrelevant to the error - I edited & removed the unnecessary part, but keep this in mind for the future...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. After changing:

`from tensorflow import keras`

to:

`import keras`

life is once again worth living.

Comment: this works :) it was due to version mismatch of keras. thanks...!

Comment: I had to do it the opposite way.

Comment: I wish to still be alive the day `keras` and `tensorflow` figure out their mutual imports once and for all. 80% of the time I spend working in machine learning is spent figuring out which import is which according to the functions I need.

Answer (score 43):

I fixed the problem:

Before:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
classifierLoad = load_model('model/modeltest.h5')
```

Works for me

```py
import tensorflow as tf 
classifierLoad = tf.keras.models.load_model('model/modeltest.h5')
```

Answer (score 30):

Wow I, just spent 6 Hours of my life trying to figure this out.. Dmitri posted a solution to this here: [I trained a keras model on google colab. Now not able to load it locally on my system.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051274/i-trained-a-keras-model-on-google-colab-now-not-able-to-load-it-locally-on-my-s)

I'm just basically reposting it here because it worked for me.

This looks like some kind of a serialization bug in keras. 
If you wrap your load_model with the below CustomObjectScope thingy... all should work..

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

with CustomObjectScope({'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}):
        model = load_model('imdb_mlp_model.h5')
```

Comment: ^ This is the only solution that worked for me when using the model within Flask

Comment: I happened to use a custom initializer , your solution worked!!!

Answer (score 15):

**Changing**

```py
from keras.models import load_model
```

**to**

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

**solved my problem!**

To eliminate errors, import **all** things directly from Keras or TensorFlow. Mixing both of them in same project may result in problems.

Comment: Thanks, the same helps me. Tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: This was the fixed for me. I guess the issue is that I found API guide for Keras is easier to follow than TF API. I guess TF API is written as a cheatsheet for folks who already mastered TF.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem and was fixed this way. just don't save the optimizer with the model!
just change the save line like this:

```
the_model.save(file_path,True/False,False)
```

Second parameter tells Keras to overwrite the model if the file existed or not and the 3rd one tells it not to save the optimizer with the model.

---

**Edit**:
I ran over the problem again on another system today and this did not helped me this time. so i saved the model conf as json and weights as h5 and used them to rebuild the model in another machine. you can do it like this.
save like this:

```
json = model.to_json()
# Save the json on a file
model.save_weights(weights_filepath,save_format="h5")
```

rebuild the model like this:

```
# load the json file
# here i use json as loaded content of json file
model = keras.models.model_from_json(json)
model.load_weights(weights_file_path)
```

Comment: I have the same problem here and I don't think this is the solution. The error occurs in this line 'model = keras.models.model_from_json(json)'

Answer (score 3):

[Something](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/798#issuecomment-452442569) that helped me which wasn't in any of the answers:

`custom_objects={'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()}`

Comment: Just to clarify, this should be included as an argument to either keras.models.load_model() or tf.keras.models.load_model()

Answer (score 3):

In either kaggle or colabs

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("model_path")
```

works well

Answer (score 2):

```
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("pruned.h5",custom_objects={'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()})
```

this worked for me when importing tensorflow keras

Comment: I happened to use a custom initializer , your solution worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you are loading the architecture and weights separtly, while loading archtiecture of the model change :

```
models.model_from_json(json)
```

to :

```
tf.keras.models.model_from_json(json)
```

and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a model built with tensorflow 1.11.0 (using tensorflow.python.keras.models.save_model) and loaded with tensoflow 1.11.0 (using tensorflow.python.keras.models.load_model).

I solved it by upgrading everything to tensorflow 1.13.1, after building the model again with the new version, I could load it without this error.

Answer (score 0):

For the json file problem mentioned by @Derk in one of the comment, you can write the following:

```
model_from_json(model_path, custom_objects = {'GlorotUniform': glorot_uniform()})
```

and in your import line, remember to write:

```
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
```

instead of `from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform`.

It worked out for me when I try to read a model saved in tf2.2 in the environment with only tf1.9.