# ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Tags: deep-learning, python, computer-vision, keras

Recently I've trained a model using MNIST dataset in Google colab. I've saved the weights using `Model.save('model.h5')`.

I've downloaded the weights and tried to run in other code by loading weights offline in anaconda `Model = Keras.models.load_model('model.h5)`.

But it throws

> ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be because you're using tf.keras and keras in a mixed way. There could also be a version mismatch between local and remote keras versions. Do check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model) on stackoverflow.