# Am I using tf.math.reduce_sum in the attention model in the right way?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, attention-model

I was trying to use the attention model described [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4962) in a simple bidirectional lstm model. However, after adding the attention model, I got this error:

> ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

To begin with, my code didn't have any incompatibility issue in terms of using TensorFlow in some part and Keras in other parts of the code. I also tried every solution addressed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model). However, none of them worked for me. I must mention that my code worked with no issues before adding the attention model. So, I tried removing every line of the attention part of the network structure to see what line is causing this problem:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
units = 50
activations = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(units,
                                                                       return_sequences=True), 
                                                                       merge_mode='concat')(inputs)
print(np.shape(activations))

# Implementation of attention
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')(activations)
print(np.shape(x1))
x1= tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x1)
print(np.shape(x1))
x1= tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(x1)
print(np.shape(x1))
x1=tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(units*2)(x1)  
print(np.shape(x1))
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Permute([2,1])(x1)
print(np.shape(x1))
sent_representation = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([activations, x1])
print(np.shape(sent_representation))
sent_representation = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda xin:tf.keras.backend.sum(xin, axis=-2),                                    
output_shape=(units*2,))(sent_representation)

# softmax for classification
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(sent_representation)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

I realized it is the line with *lambda function* and *tf.keras.backend.sum* that is causing the error. So, after some search I decided to replace that line with the following:

```
sent_representation = tf.math.reduce_sum(sent_representation, axis=-2)
```

Now, my code works. However, I am not quite sure if this substitution is correct. Am I doing this right?

Edit: Here is the next lines of the code, the problem is caused when I try to load the best model for testing:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9)   
model.compile(loss=lossFunction, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

# early stopping
es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', 
verbose=1, patience=20)
mc = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', 
monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(valX, valy),
                    shuffle = True, epochs=epochs, verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[es, mc])  
saved_model =  tf.keras.models.load_model('best_model.h5',
                                          custom_objects={"GlorotUniform": tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform()})
# evaluate the model
_, train_acc = saved_model.evaluate(trainX, trainy, verbose=0)  # saved_model
_, val_acc = saved_model.evaluate(valX, valy, verbose=0)  # saved_model
_, accuracy = saved_model.evaluate(testX, testy, verbose=0)  # saved_model
print('Train: %.3f, Validation: %.3f, Test: %.3f' % (train_acc, val_acc, accuracy))
y_pred = saved_model.predict(testX, batch_size=64, verbose=1)
```

Do you see any problem in my code that might be the cause of the error that I get when I use Lambda layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided works for me without problem with `tf.keras.backend.sum` and with `tf.math.reduce_sum`

The answer is that your substitution doesn't alter your network or what you are you looking for. You can test it on your own and verify that `tf.keras.backend.sum` is equal to `tf.math.reduce_sum`

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (32,100,10)).astype('float32')

(tf.keras.backend.sum(X, axis=-2) == tf.reduce_sum(X, axis=-2)).numpy().all() # TRUE
```

I also suggest you to wrap the operation with a Lambda layer

**EDIT**: the usage of `tf.reduce_sum` or `tf.keras.backend.sum`, wrapped in a Lambda layer, don't raise error if using a TF version >= 2.2.

In the model building, you need to use layers only. If you want to use some tensorflow ops (like `tf.reduce_sum` or `tf.keras.backend.sum`) you need to wrap them in keras Lambda layer. Without this the model can still work but using Lambda is a good practice in order to avoid future problem

Comment: Do you mean something like this: sent_representation = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda xin: tf.math.reduce_sum(xin, axis=-2), output_shape=(units*2,))(sent_representation). Because I get the same error. So, I guess the problem is with Lambda layer. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I don't have any problem: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uT9oPhkS8ygEg0f1XGZk5XT7nOoHU-Kx?usp=sharing

Comment: as before no problems, also after saving and loading models https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1asLmi54MXnMHtZKd7TPYdZ7H-xtNxMcv?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you make a guess about the cause of this problem?

Comment: but what is the error that raises using Lambda layer?

Comment: ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Comment: if u do a trial with a simpe tf.keras.layer:LSTM instead of tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM but it seems strange

Comment: I did try tf.keras.layers.LSTM as well and get the exact same error

Comment: which is your tf version ?

Comment: tensorflow version: 2.1.0

Comment: I downgrade on colab on 2.1 and it raises an error (not the same as yours)... the last thing I can suggest u is to upgrade to 2.3 (in my example it doesn't raise errors)

Comment: I will try that and will let you know of the result

Comment: I upgraded to tensorflow 2.2 (I was using conda and 2.3 is not still available) and problem resolved. Can you please add version upgrade to your answer, so that I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: Also can you add something to your answer about why to wrap the operation with a Lambda layer? Is it gonna cause any issue if it is not applied?

Comment: Nice to hear about this... I edited... don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)