# Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform with Keras in Cube.AI

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, stm32, google-colaboratory

This problem is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051274/i-trained-a-keras-model-on-google-colab-now-not-able-to-load-it-locally-on-my-s)
However it *is not* a duplicate question for the reasons I am going to explain.

The premise is the same: I trained a model in Keras (TensorFlow) using google Colab and when trying to use it locally I got the error: *Unknown Initializer: GlorotUniform*.

That is where the similarities end. 
In the linked questions, the answers seem to add some imports *when loading the model in the local system*

However I cannot do that because I am using my trained h5 model in the STMCube.AI module (which is a module to load a h5 keras model and translate it into C code to be used by a STM microcontroller)

I suppose that I cannot modify how the script of Cube.AI loads the model (as the answers in the links suggest) so my question is: Is there a way to correct this *when generating the model*??

Comment: This error happens when you save a model with tf.keras and you try to load it with keras, is that the case? Both libraries are not compatible in that way.

Comment: One of the sources I am learning from uses KEras. The other source uses tf.keras and they don't have a problem. The problems seems to be in a different version being used by Cube.AI

Comment: I don't think you answered my question: model saved with tf.keras and loaded with keras (or viceversa).