# ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I made a CNN in colab and saved the models at every epoch. I exported the h5 file and now am trying to run the model on some test images. Here's the main error:

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

Here's the code I used to run the model and save at each epoch:

```
epochs = 50

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs'),
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("save_at_{epoch}.h5"),
]
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.fit(
    train_ds, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=val_ds,
)
```

After the model ran I just downloaded the h5 file from the colab sidebar locally. I re-uploaded the file from the local disk, and here's how I'm trying to load the model:

```
# load and evaluate a saved model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

# load model#
loaded_model = load_model('save_at_47.h5')
loaded_model.layers[0].input_shape
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6af7396280fa> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # load model#
----> 5 loaded_model = load_model('save_at_47.h5')
      6 loaded_model.layers[0].input_shape

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    182     if (h5py is not None and (
    183         isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 184       return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    185 
    186     if sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(filepath, pathlib.Path):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    176     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    177     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
--> 178                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
    179 
    180     # set weights

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
     53                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
     54   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 55   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
     56 
     57 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    107       module_objects=globs,
    108       custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 109       printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    360     config = identifier
    361     (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
--> 362         config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    363 
    364     if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    319   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    320   if cls is None:
--> 321     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    322 
    323   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

It seems there have been several similar [questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051274/i-trained-a-keras-model-on-google-colab-now-not-able-to-load-it-locally-on-my-s),and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53183865/unknown-initializer-glorotuniform-when-loading-keras-model). Changing the import method hasn't helped yet, and trying to make some [kind of custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286368/valueerror-unknown-layername-when-loading-a-keras-model) object has not worked either.

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you're using to save the model, please?

Comment: Of course, I updated the question to show how I saved the model to disk. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you reconstruct the model yourself from scratch and load the weights (`model.load_weights('save_at_47.h5')`) from the `h5` file?

Comment: What is this layer called Functional in your error? Is it a custom layer made by you?

Comment: Hi @Dr. Snoopy, I was trying to figure out the same thing, I got most of the code from the [Keras Image classification from scratch](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Reza Behzadpour, I may try to build the model from scratch, but not too sure how to do that either at the moment.

Comment: Easy peasy. Just run the cells which contain the definition and compiling of your model and then load the weights to this bare and empty model as I told you above.

Comment: Easy peasy lemon squeezy it worked! Thanks @Reza Behzadpour !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rebuilt the network from scratch:

```
image_size = (212, 212)
batch_size = 32

data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.8),
    ]
)


def make_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Image augmentation block
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)

    # Entry block
    x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    for size in [128, 256, 512, 728]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(size, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(size, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    x = layers.SeparableConv2D(1024, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    if num_classes == 2:
        activation = "sigmoid"
        units = 1
    else:
        activation = "softmax"
        units = num_classes

    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


model = make_model(input_shape=image_size + (3,), num_classes=2)
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=False)
```

Loaded the weights:

```
model.load_weights('save_at_47.h5')
```

And ran a prediction on an image:

```
# Running inference on new data
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    "le_image.jpg", target_size=image_size
)
img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = predictions[0]
print(
    "This image is %.2f percent negative and %.2f percent positive."
    % (100 * (1 - score), 100 * score)
)
```

Comment: Is this something specific to Colab? I've got the same error.

Comment: You save my life! ;P

Comment: @LobstaBoy The solution wasn't entirely connected. You complained about `load_model('save_at_47.h5')` not working, and in the answer you have suggested using `load_weights` instead. So, what if I would want `load_model` to work as it should; what would be the solution ?

Comment: @VM_AI there seemed to be some kind of version compatibility issue which required switching versions back and forth to get the model to load, which seems like more of a pain than loading the weights into the model. I'm not even sure why it gave me the error to begin with since I was saving and loading models into the same colab environment.

Comment: @LobstaBoy I think loading weights is as well defective because when you load weights using `model.load_weights(filename)` and retrain the model, the error should start from that of recent checkpoint. Instead, it starts from the error you would have got from the first epoch. I am still looking for solutions on how to save and load weights/model properly.

Answer (score 21):

The solution to this error is very simple, ex. the reason is that you have trained the model on version '2.3.0' of Tensorflow & '2.4.3' of Keras (On Colab or local). and now you are accessing the saved model(.h5) via another version of Keras & TensorFlow. It will give you the error. The solution is that re-trained model with upgraded versions or downgrades your TF&Keras to the same version as on which model is trained.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did you know that the error happened on this specific '2.3.0' version?

Comment: Is the "functional" layer new in version 2.3.0?

Answer (score 5):

The following trick can be useful if you are using older TF (in my case 2.1.0) and trying to unpack h5 file packed by newer TF (e.g. 2.4.1) and facing this error.

```
your_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(
    path_to_h5,
    custom_objects={'Functional':tf.keras.models.Model})
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when i was on tf 2.3.0, i downgraded to tf 2.2.0 and it worked

Comment: I'm using CoLab with tf, so I could downgrade the versions each time I open a workspace, but it may be cumbersome after a while. Good to know though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem when training model with `tf 2.3` on colab and load them with `tf 2.2` in my local machine. The solution is to upgrade TensorFlow with this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

The discussion here saved me some trouble! I share a different solution for a **similar situation** where model serialization is done manually (not from the fit method) using a model structure (yaml) and h5 weights file. In this case simply editing the yaml file was sufficient to adapt the serialized model for an older tensorflow version.

In my case I generated the model like this

```
    model_config = { "class_name": "Model",
                     "config":model.get_config()
                     }

    with open(os.path.join(dump_model_dir, "model_config.yaml"), "w") as file:
        file.write(model.to_yaml())

    model.save_weights(os.path.join(dump_model_dir, "model_weights.hdf5"))
```

Doing this with TF2.2 and 2.3 reveals a minor change in the yaml file. The diff for the two versions for a model structure with only Conv2D layers is shown below. It simple to fix manually or with sed:

One needs to change `class_name: Functional` into `class_name: Model` and remove the config `groups: 1` that is new in Conv2D and probably other Conv layers. For consistency I also changed the keras version at the end. Obviously this will work only if the groups parameter of the model in question has the default value `1`. A similar solution should apply if you don't use yaml but json files for the model.

```
*** model_config_tf22.yaml  2021-01-07 15:00:03.042791215 +0100
--- model_config_tf23.yaml  2021-01-07 14:59:56.426791386 +0100
***************
*** 1,5 ****
  backend: tensorflow
! class_name: Model
  config:
    input_layers:
    - - input_1
--- 1,5 ----
  backend: tensorflow
! class_name: Functional
  config:
    input_layers:
    - - input_1
***************
*** 34,39 ****
--- 34,40 ----
        - 1
        dtype: float32
        filters: 128
+       groups: 1
        kernel_constraint: null
        kernel_initializer:
          class_name: RandomUniform
***************
*** 343,346 ****
    - - Conv2D_5_37
      - 0
      - 0
! keras_version: 2.3.0-tf
--- 351,354 ----
    - - Conv2D_5_37
      - 0
      - 0
! keras_version: 2.4.0
```

Comment: Where did you make these changes? In the Python code that defines the Keras model?

Comment: No, I am sorry if this was not clear enough. This solution is solving the same problem as the original question for the case where serialization is done using a model structure file in yaml or json format and a weights file. I edited the solution to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: thank you so much, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install and upgrade:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
!pip install keras_efficientnet_v2
!pip install efficientnet
```