# ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional Keras load_model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
```

is giving me error as,

```
ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name) ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

I tried setting path `model_path = "{}{}".format(Path().absolute(),"/model_new.h5")`
using tensorflow -2.2.0 and keras -2.4.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068639/valueerror-unknown-layer-functional

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional

You are getting above error, because you trained the model using `Tensorflow 2.2.0` and then tried to accessing the saved model( i.e `model_new.h5`) using different version of Tensorflow.

To fix above problem you can try to load the model using `Tensorflow 2.2.0`.  (Or)

If you don't want to downgrade tensorflow version then you can try to retrained model using the same version.